# JQuery Load doesn't load live

Tags: php, html, jquery, time, trending

I'm using JQuery in a PHP file to load the files of another content called 'live.php' which displays time(), but it doesn't load live. Why is this happening? It used to work.

MAIN.PHP

```
    echo "<div id='x'></div>";
    echo '<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">';
    echo '$(document).ready(function() {
            $("#x").load("live.php");
        });';
    echo '</script>';
```

LIVE.PHP

```
<?php echo time();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missed the closing PHP tag in the `LIVE.PHP`
**It must be like:**  `<?php echo time(); ?>`
You have missed the `?>` in your PHP file, so the PHP file would not work. So **make sure you add** `?>` to your `LIVE.PHP`
And for **displaying live time without refreshing the page**, you can use this **jQuery**:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){  
        setInterval(function(){   
            $("#x").load("live.php");
        }, 1000);
    });
```

This updates the page every 1 second.
You can change the `1000` to your desired limit (The 1000 stands for 1000 miliseconds)

Comment: No, the PHP works fine. It just doesn't load constantly. I have to refresh the page to see the time() change.

Comment: I have edited the answer :) See if this helps in anyway!

Comment: Thanks, but the time() was just an example. The real issue was loading a whole PHP file without refreshing. I don't really want to show the time() live.

Comment: I guess you can just echo the time() in the main.php file, so that you don't have to refresh the page everytime :)

Comment: I said... time() was an example. I want to load the content from another file LIVE, but the function LOAD() is not working